# How to avoid adding field change handling methods and other boilerplates in react form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react based form with more than 10 fields in it, I have **states** for those ten `form` fields **(controlled component)**.

Most of these `input` fields are of type `text` only but other types fields will be added later.

Problem is that I need to write **10 change handlers** for them to set state correctly and then add method bindings for each of them in **constructor**.

> I am quite new to react and may be not aware about correct
>   methodologies and techniques.

Please guide me to how to improve my current code structure and avoid writing boiler plates and repetitive error prone code.

My current Registration component is like below -

```
export default class Register extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            regName              : '',
            regAdd1              : '',
            regAdd2              : '',
            regState             : '',
            regZipCode           : '',
            regCity              : '',
            regPhone             : ''
        };
        // add bindings .... ugh..
        this.changeRegAdd1 = this.changeRegAdd1.bind(this);
        this.changeRegAdd2 = this.changeRegAdd2.bind(this);
        //Similary binding for other handlers...
    }

    // add individual field change handlers ... ugh...
    changeRegName(e) {
        this.setState({regName:e.target.value});
    }

    changeRegAdd1(e) {
        this.setState({regAdd1:e.target.value});
    }

    changeRegAdd2(e) {
        this.setState({regAdd2:e.target.value});
    }

    changeRegState(e) {
        this.setState({regState:e.target.value});
    }


    // Similary for other change handler ....

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // validate then do other stuff
    }

    render(){

        let registrationComp = (
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <h3>Registration Form</h3>
                        <fieldset>
                              <div className="form-group">
                                <div className="col-xs-12">
                                    <label htmlFor="regName">Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Name"
                                        onChange={this.changeregName} value = {this.state.regName} className="form-control" required autofocus/>
                                </div>
                              </div>

                              <div className="form-group">
                                <div className="col-xs-12">
                                    <label htmlFor="regAdd1">Address Line1</label>

                                    <input
                                        type        = "text"
                                        placeholder = "Address Line1"
                                        onChange    = {this.changeregAdd1}
                                        value       = {this.state.regAdd1}
                                        className   = "form-control"
                                        required
                                        autofocus
                                    />

                                    <input
                                        type        = "text"
                                        placeholder = "Address Line2"
                                        onChange    = {this.changeregAdd2}
                                        value       = {this.state.regAdd2}
                                        className   = "form-control"
                                        required
                                        autofocus
                                    />
                                </div>
                              </div>

                              <div className="form-group">
                                <div className="col-xs-6">
                                    <label htmlFor="regState">State</label>
                                    <input
                                        type        = "text"
                                        placeholder = "State"
                                        onChange    = {this.changeregState}
                                        value       = {this.state.regState}
                                        className   = "form-control"
                                        required
                                        autofocus
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-xs-6">
                                    <label htmlFor="regZipCode">Zip Code</label>
                                    <input
                                        type        = "text"
                                        placeholder = "Zip Code"
                                        onChange    = {this.changeregZipCode}
                                        value       = {this.state.regZipCode}
                                        className   = "form-control"
                                        required
                                        autofocus
                                    />
                                </div>
                              </div>

                              <div className="form-group">
                                <div className="col-xs-12">
                                    <label htmlFor="regCity">City</label>
                                    <input
                                        type        = "text"
                                        placeholder = "City"
                                        title       = "City"
                                        onChange    = {this.changeregCity}
                                        value       = {this.state.regCity}
                                        className   = "form-control"
                                        required
                                        autofocus
                                    />
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              {/* other form fields */}
                          </fieldset>
                      </div>
                    </div>
            );

            return  registrationComp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can be other lots of ways to do it which I may not be aware.

But I prefer to do change handling in a common method for certain type of common fields such as  `<input type of text />`

This is a sample input field -

```
  <input
      onChange    = {this.onChange}
      value       = {this.state.firstName}
      type        = "text"
      name        = {"firstName"}
  />
```

I keep both state's field name and input's **"name"** attribute same.
After that I write a **common change handler** for all such fields.

Need to write just one line in change handler.

```
onChange(e) {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
}
```

I am using es6's dynamic property setting from string as property name

```
{ ["propName] : propValue }.
```

To avoid writing manual binding for methods in react component you can follow below two approaches -

1. Use es6 arrow functions
2. A hack ( I don't know whether this approach is fast or slow but It works :) )

create a method like this in your component.

```
_bind(...methods) {
  methods.forEach( (method) => this[method] = this[method].bind(this) );
 }
```

use `_bind` to bind your methods.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        regName              : '',
        regAdd1              : '',
        regAdd2              : '',
        regState             : '',
        regZipCode           : '',
        regCity              : '',
        regPhone             : ''
    };
    // add bindings .... ugh..
    //this.changeRegAdd1 = this.changeRegAdd1.bind(this);
    //this.changeRegAdd2 = this.changeRegAdd2.bind(this);
    //Similary binding for other handlers...

    this._bind(
        'changeRegName',
        'changeReg1'    , 'changeRegAdd2'
        // and so on.
    );


}
```

**EDIT :**

Adding validation -

1. Write a method which can iterate over state keys and check if state is empty.
2. If any of the input field is empty collect the detail about that input and mark that required.
3. set a state to indicate that form has errors. Specific error details can be found in state's error object.

   ```
   validateInput() {
       let errors = {};

       Object.keys(this.state)
       .forEach((stateKey) => {
       isEmpty(this.state[stateKey]) ? (errors[stateKey] = `*required` ) : null;
   });

       return {
          errors,
          isValid : isEmptyObj(errors)
      };
   }

   isFormValid() {
      const { errors, isValid } = this.validateInput();

      if (!isValid) {
         this.setState({ errors});
      }

      return isValid;
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        this.setState({errors : {}});

        if (this.isFormValid()) {
           // Perform form submission
        }
     }
   ```

I have used to utility method calld `isEmpty`, `isEmptyObj`. They just check if object is null or undefined or field is empty.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You could also initially set to controlled `value = {this.state.firstName || ''}`, you don't need that mass state list of inputs

Comment: @DarrenSweeney in the constructor itself you can initialize that value to empty string. But what you proposed that can also be done.

Comment: Yeah I know but if you do it within the component you don't have to worry about updating the initial state if you add more inputs, just cleaner to me

Answer (score 2):

You could create a higher order component to handle a lot of that for you. [Redux Form](https://redux-form.com) has a pretty good pattern you could model it after if you wanted.

You would essentially end up with something like the following (I have not tested this at all, but it should work pretty well):

```
export class Field extends Component {
  handleChange = (event) => this.props.onChange(this.props.name, event.target.value)

  render() {
    const InputComponent = this.props.component
    const value = this.props.value || ''

    return (
      <InputComponent
        {...this.props}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        value={value}
      />
  }
}

export default function createForm(WrappedComponent) {
  class Form extends Component {
    constructor() {
      super()

      this.state = this.props.initialValues || {}
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(name, value) {
      this.setState({
        [name]: value,
      })
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <WrappedComponent
          {...this.state}
          {...this.props}
          // pass anything you want to add here
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          values={this.state}
        />
      )
    }
  }

  return Form
}
```

Then you can augment this one component as necessary (add focus, blur, submit handlers, etc). You would use it something like this:

```
import createForm, { Field } from './createForm'

// simplified Registration component
export class Registration extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <Field
          component="input"
          name="name"
          onChange={this.props.onChange}
          type="text"
          value={this.props.values.name}
        />
      </form> 
    )
  }
}

export default createForm(Registration)
```

You could go crazy and get into [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) so you don't have to manually pass values and function around, but I would stay away at least until you're more familiar with React.

Also, if you don't want to manually bind functions, you could use [the class properties transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) if you're using babel. Then the `Form` component would just look like the following:

```
class Form extends Component {
  state = this.props.initialValues || {}

  handleChange = (name, value) => this.setState({
    [name]: value,
  })

  render() {
    return (
      <WrappedComponent
        {...this.state}
        {...this.props}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        values={this.state}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how it's done in [NeoForm](https://github.com/zero-plus-x/neoform):

- data state is directly mapped to form fields
- one `onChange` handler for the entire form
- per-field (for example `onBlur`) and form (for example `onSubmit`) validation
- plain object and Immutable state helpers
- easy integration with Redux or any other state management solution

It uses `context` internally and really small and modular source code is easy to follow.